# Difference between 'bundle' and 'bundle install' rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, bundle, bundler

I've been working with Rails 3 for some time now and never came across an answer for the difference between running `bundle` and `bundle install` to install gems in your `Gemfile`.

Is there any difference between the two commands?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

No.  `install` is just the default option for the `bundle` command.  Don't run either in your Gemfile, however, just specify the `gem "fubar"` there -- bundler knows how to read and process that file.